# Smarty: Use Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, multidimensional-array, smarty

I want to build a Google Map with multiple markers in Smarty (V 3.1.30). The roughly 200 entries come from a MySQL Database, are stored in a multidimensional Array and assigned to a Smarty Template.

Each Entry has the Structure:

```
 [ID, "Name", "City", lat, lng]
```

In the Template file I want to build the Map with JavaScript. The Problem is, that I don't succeed in getting the array from the Template and using it in the JavaScript. The Security Options in Smarty are not enabled.

I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  {literal}
    var locations = {/literal}{$allCoords|json_encode}{literal};
    console.log(locations);
  {/literal}   
</script>
```

… And get this error in the console:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'
>   var locations = ;

Comment: send array in JSON format..

Comment: My bet is `json_encode` failed. You should run that on your controller end and check for errors

Comment: What do you mean with "run on your Controller"? Please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advices. It was a Problem with the charset and that caused, that JSON failed.

Javascript can't work with php-Arrays but with JSON-Objects.
JSON needs UTF8.